# 'Cannot redirect to nil' error after adding a field to devise registration view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.1

After adding this line to the devise/registrations/new.html.haml file (view):

```
  %div
    = f.label :account_type
    %br/
    = f.select(:account_type, [["Usertype1","usertype1"],["Usertype2","usertype2"]], {:selected => nil, :prompt => 'Pick One'})
```

I get the following error after clicking on the confirmation link in the confirmation e-mail:

```
ActionController::ActionControllerError in Devise::ConfirmationsController#show

Cannot redirect to nil!
```

It only happens if I select Usertype2 upon registration.  I also made the account_type attr_accessible.  The account_type seems to be getting assigned (I checked in the rails console) and the development logs don't have any further information.

I think this is the line in the devise confirmations controller where the error is occurring:

```
respond_with_navigational(resource){ redirect_to after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource) }
```

Also, the account is being confirmed, but when trying to log in, I get the following:

```
undefined method `user_url' for #<Devise::SessionsController:0x9d1659c>
```

which is in the create action of the devise sessions controller.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

John

Answer (score 5):

The two errors you mentioned are one and the same, essentially when you are signing-in successfully Devise is unable to detect where to redirect you. This problem often occurs when you have multiple models or try to setup a custom redirect (post sign in) in the routes file.

Try to define the path in the ApplicationController.

Devise docs say that the after_sign_in_path_for method takes the actual model object (ie: the model being signed-in)

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    signed_in_path_for_user
end
```

Note: You can do the same for several Devise paths / variables (override them). Also for more information on doing this for multiple Devise models in the same app, you can look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808335/unable-to-sign-in-for-a-user-resource-nomethod-error-in-devise-sessionscontrol) and it's answer.